# Finding class instance based on unique attribute.

Tags: excel, vba, class, oop

I am trying to learn about class modules in VBA for Excel. I have a **cAssociate** class which has **Name**and **Number** attributes.

- Is there a way to make sure that the Number remains unique?
- Finally, I would like to be able to do something like `GetName(Number as Long)` to get the name of the associate based on the number.

I know how this can be done with a for loop, I would like to know if this can done in a better way without looping through the entire Collection of Associates.

Comment: You need to store your `Associate` instances somewhere, so you could make an `Associates` class to hold them: that class would manage the uniqueness of `Number` and accessing Name by Number.  Inside that class you could maybe use a Dictionary to handle some of that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a different example, but here's how I uniquely ID my classes. I have a bunch of CCountry class instances inside this CCountries collection class. When I add them

```
Public Sub Add(clsCountry As CCountry)
    If clsCountry.CountryID = 0 Then
        clsCountry.CountryID = Me.Count + 1
    End If

    mcolCountries.Add clsCountry, CStr(clsCountry.CountryID)
End Sub
```

I assign a sequential number to the ID property and use the string representation of that number as the key in my private collection.  Now I can retrieve any CCountry by the key number

```
Public Property Get Country(vItem As Variant) As CCountry
    Set Country = mcolCountries.Item(vItem)
End Property
```

Notice that vItem is a Variant. If I pass a String, it will return the Colleciton item whose key is that string. If I pass a Long, it will return the nth Item in the Collection. When your keys are string representations of numbers, that can lead to mistakes (you think you're getting key="10" but you're really getting the 10th item), so be careful.

When you said you wanted to ensure uniqueness, you probably didn't mean to haphazardly assign IDs like I do. You probably already have a number and just don't want to duplicate. But by making that (string representation of the) number the key to your collection, it will ensure uniqueness by giving you a duplicate key error. And if you use a Scripting.Dictionary instead of a Collection you can use the Exists method to handle that problem gracefully.

Finally, don't give up on loops so easily. Yes there are better ways, but as the saying goes 'don't optimize until you measure'. You can do a lot of gyrations to avoid a loop that takes a millisecond. Take this Property

```
Public Property Get CountryBy(ByVal sProperty As String, ByVal vValue As Variant) As CCountry

    Dim clsReturn As CCountry
    Dim clsCountry As CCountry

    For Each clsCountry In Me
        If CallByName(clsCountry, sProperty, VbGet) = vValue Then
            Set clsReturn = clsCountry
            Exit For
        End If
    Next clsCountry

    Set CountryBy = clsReturn

End Property
```

It loops, but it stops looping once it finds a match. That could still mean going through the whole list or it could mean stopping after the first CCountry. But if it doesn't add performance issues, then don't waste your time fixing it.

Comment: Marking this as correct because of simplicity of answer and relevance to my particular use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a class module called cAssociate:

```
Private pName As String
Private pNumber As Integer


Public Property Let Name(ByRef vName As String)

pName = vName

End Property

Public Property Let Number(ByVal vNumber As Integer)

pNumber = vNumber

End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String

Name = pName

End Property

Public Property Get Number() As Integer

Number = pNumber

End Property
```

And in a class module called cAssociates:

```
Option Explicit
Private assocs As Collection
Private lastID As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set assocs = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set assocs = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(obj As cAssociate)
    lastID = lastID + 1
    obj.Number = lastID
    assocs.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(Index As Variant)
    assocs.Remove Index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As cAssociate
    Set Item = assocs.Item(Index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = assocs.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set assocs = New Collection
End Sub

Public Function GetName(ByVal Number As Long) As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To assocs.Count
    If assocs.Item(i).Number() = Number Then
        GetName = assocs.Item(i).Name
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

And here's a test, to be put in a normal module:

```
Sub TestGetName()


Dim ass As New cAssociates
Dim a As cAssociate

Dim i As Integer


For i = 0 To 10
    Set a = New cAssociate
    If i = 4 Then
        a.Name = "Garry"
    Else
        a.Name = "Belle"
    End If
    ass.Add a
Next i

Debug.Print ass.GetName(5)


End Sub
```

What this does is provide a custom collection class that assigns every new entry a unique ID (it's number). It has an extra method which allows you to find a name by its id (called GetName(integer))

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think I was very clear in my question. I already have numbers for the each of the associates and do not need to generate numbers for them. Very detailed answer!